# Отправка электронной почты в Джанго с помощью smtp

Tags: python, django, smtp

на моем сайте я пытаюсь сбросить свой пароль по электронной почте с помощью smtp, но когда я отправляю запрос на изменение пароля, я получаю эту ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мои setting.py :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'expresstest177@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "ibuc pvmq fkgb acah"
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
    
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
    SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
    EMAIL_ADMIN = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

и urls.py, если необходимо:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='main/password_reset_form.html',
        email_template_name='main/password_reset_email.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('user:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),   

    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='main/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='main/password_reset_confirm.html',
        success_url=reverse_lazy('user:password_reset_complete')), name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('password-reset/complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='main/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

В чем может быть проблема?